# Index every n-th element along each dimension of a N-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In one dimension it is possible to do:

```
np.arange(12)[::3]
```

to obtain:

```
array([0, 3, 6, 9])
```

**What is an efficient way to do the same for N-dimensions?**

For example, given:

```
np.random.random((10, 15, 20))
```

how to obtain every third element in along each dimension?

Comment: What would be the expected outcome for something like `np.arange(10*15*20).reshape(4, 15, 20)`?

Comment: For example, when the array contains some image data, it would amount to downsampling images. Dimensions can be: height, width, depth, time, channels, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 3d, you can do:

```
a = np.random.random((10, 15, 20))

a[::3,::3,::3].shape
# (4, 5, 7)

a.shape
# (10, 15, 20)
```

For arbitrary dimension, you might use `slice`:

```
a[[slice(None,None,3)] * a.ndim].shape
# (4, 5, 7)
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know about this trick with `slice`. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad it can help!